# sp_MSForEachDB Invalid Use of Side-Effecting Operator Within Function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamic, metadata

Is there anyway to put the below code into a Table-Valued (inline or multi-statement) or even a View.  I'm able to use it in a stored procedure but do to the inability to do joins to the results of stored procedures I'd rather put it in a Table-Valued function or View.

Below is the SQL that gives me the results I'm looking for

```
DECLARE @ColumnInformation TABLE
(
    DatabaseName NVARCHAR(255),
    TableSchema NVARCHAR(255),
    TableName NVARCHAR(255),
    ColumnName NVARCHAR(255),
    TableType NVARCHAR(255),
    FullyQualifiedTableName NVARCHAR(255),
    FullyQualifiedColumnName NVARCHAR(255)
)
INSERT INTO @ColumnInformation
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSForEachDB  '
IF ''?'' NOT IN (''master'', ''tempdb'', ''msdb'', ''model'', ''ReportServer'', ''ReportServerTempDB'' )
BEGIN
    USE [?];
    PRINT ''?''
    SELECT 
         T.TABLE_CATALOG AS DatabaseName
        ,T.TABLE_SCHEMA as TableSchema  
        ,T.TABLE_NAME AS TableName
        ,C.COLUMN_NAME AS ColumnName
        ,T.TABLE_TYPE AS TableType
        ,''['' + T.TABLE_CATALOG + ''].['' + T.TABLE_SCHEMA + ''].['' + T.TABLE_NAME + '']'' AS FullyQualifiedTableName
        ,''['' + T.TABLE_CATALOG + ''].['' + T.TABLE_SCHEMA + ''].['' + T.TABLE_NAME + ''].['' + C.COLUMN_NAME + '']'' FullyQualifiedColumnName
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES as t inner join
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as c on c.table_name = t.table_name
END
'

SELECT * 
FROM @ColumnInformation
ORDER BY DatabaseName, TableSchema, TableName, ColumnName
```

however when I try to put it in a table valued function I'm getting the error

```
Msg 443, Level 16, State 14, Procedure fGetAllColumnInformation, Line 17
Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT EXEC' within a function.
```

I believe that sp_MSForEachDb is generating dynamic SQL but not real sure. I vaguely remember hearing that dynamic SQL can not be used in table-valued functions.  If this is the case is there anyway of bypassing that restriction so that I can use the above code in a table-valued function or view.

If the answer to the above is no...is there any way of rewriting the statement so that it does not use dynamic SQL?

I'm basically trying to union the results of all of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS from every database on a SQL Server.

Comment: Well part of the question was "If the answer to the above is no...is there any way of rewriting the statement so that it does not use dynamic SQL?"  I know spMSForEachDB may be deprecated in the future and if it is I'll just have to write my own that does what I need it to do.

Comment: Also the replacement of sp_MSForEachDB that you mentioned http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/ does not work in my scenario.  It bombs out unless I comment out the USE [?] line.  And if that is commented out I only get info from the master database or which ever database I am currently using.

Comment: I get a Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Database '[SomeDatabase];
  PRINT '[SomeDatabase' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

Comment: On a side note when I try to use the Insert Statement with the modified sp_foreachdb I get another error.

Msg 8164, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_foreachdb, Line 86
An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.

so it's not truly a replacement to the MS proc.

Comment: and no...no square brackets in the name.  The message that got printed put brackets around the name on 2nd line and left out the right side bracket on the third line.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand  I noticed you deleted your comments and were also the author of that modified stored procedure.  I was checking your stored procedure if I execute this statement EXECUTE master.dbo.sp_foreachdb  'USE [?];'  I get an "Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '[SomeDatabaseName];'  I do have a few underscores in some of the database names but no other weird characters.

Comment: Try `USE ?` instead of `USE [?]`. The procedure already handles the quoting for you. As the article states: *Also, you do not need to QUOTENAME parameter values... you should pass in 'master, model' to @database_list, not '[master], [model]', and you should use 'USE ?;' and not 'USE [?];' for the command and replace_character values - this escaping is handled for you. *

Comment: Anyway my answer is a better way to do it without all of the problems you're having implementing my replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this dynamically (as in without hard-coding all the database names in advance) without dynamic SQL, and you can't use dynamic SQL in a function. You [shouldn't be using sp_MSForEachDB in any case](https://sqlblog.org/2020/01/31/reliable-flexible-replacement-sp_msforeachdb) or, IMHO, [using INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views).

Write a stored procedure that returns the result set. If you absolutely need to join the output to other stuff (why not code that into the stored procedure?), then insert the output into a #temp table.

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.AllMyColumnsEverywhereForReals
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

  SELECT @sql += '
  UNION ALL SELECT 
      [database]  = N''' + d.name + ''' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI,
      [schema]    = s.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI,
      [object]    = o.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI,
      [column]    = c.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI,
      [qualified] = QUOTENAME(''' + d.name + ''') 
        + ''.'' + QUOTENAME(s.name) 
        + ''.'' + QUOTENAME(c.name) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
      [type] = CASE o.type WHEN ''U'' THEN ''Table'' ELSE ''View'' END
    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.sys.columns AS c
      INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.sys.objects AS o
      ON c.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
      INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.sys.schemas AS s
      ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
      WHERE o.type IN (''U'', ''V'')'
  FROM sys.databases AS d WHERE [state] = 0 AND name NOT IN 
    (N'master',N'tempdb',N'msdb',N'model',N'ReportServer',N'ReportServerTempDB');

  SET @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, 13, '');

  EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
GO
```

Usage:

```
CREATE TABLE #x
(
  db     SYSNAME, 
  sch    SYSNAME, 
  obj    SYSNAME, 
  col    SYSNAME, 
  qual   NVARCHAR(390),
  [type] CHAR(5)
);

INSERT #x EXEC dbo.AllMyColumnsEverywhereForReals;

SELECT cols FROM #x AS x -- INNER JOIN something else ON x.whatever...
```

Comment: Thanks this appears to work for what I intended.  Other than the performance overhead of reinserting the results from the stored procedure into a temporary table I like it...but if that's the only way I guess it's the only way.  I'll give it 1 day unless I see any better answers I'll accept this one.  BTW why are you putting all of the COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI everywhere?

Comment: You're worried about performance overhead? How often are you running this? Usually performance overhead isn't the primary concern for infrequent, one-off administrative/maintenance tasks.

Comment: The collation references are there because if you have databases with different collation, the metadata will yield to errors like `Msg 451 Cannot resolve collation conflict between...`

Comment: Yeah I guess your right about performance...it really shouldn't be too much of a concern for this.  Thanks for info on the COLLATE I don't do much with multiple databases at one time.

Comment: Also thanks for your inclusion of SYSNAME datatype.  I was unaware of that type and was just using nvarchar(255) for those.