# creating system table valued function

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to create `system table valued function` that can be run on any DB.
In analogy with SP

```
use master;
create procedure sp_test
as
begin select 1 end;

exec sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject sp_test
```

This SP can be executed on any DB within server. I'm looking for same example in TVF.

Comment: I don't see any issue,why can't you try once on test instance

Comment: @TheGameiswar, I did that didn't work. Is there any naming convention for TVF?

Comment: @TheGameiswar, can you post the same simple example as above to make it clear?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17840940/6167855

Answer (score 0):

After going through all forums, there is no way to make system functions. Only stored procedures and tables can be done system.

Answer (score -1):

Is using the database name when referencing the function an option? If so you could just create your function...

```
USE Master
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.yourITVF()
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
SELECT * FROM <some table>;
GO
```

Then run it like this from any DB on the instance:

```
SELECT * FROM master.dbo.yourITVF();
```

Comment: But I want to make it system TVF, not use 4 part identifier, since inside TVF are tables that I want to use on each particular DB, Like the same analogy with SP described above

Comment: I'm not aware of anyway you can do the same thing you are doing with the stored proc in your example with an ITVF. I was just offering an alternative/work-around.